# Access to SQL 2008 Server with ODBC

Tags: sql-server-2008, odbc

what do you think about using an SQL-ODBC-driver (SQLSRV32.DLL) with the name 'SQL SERVER' for accessing a SQL Server 2008 Server database?

A first look shows that it works but is there something like upward combatibility?

Peace
Ice

Answer (score 2):

If possible, I would get a current ODBC driver.  I don't know what kind of backward compatibility SQL Server 2008 has been given for older ODBC drivers, so I would tread carefully.

What that means in practice is that if it works, great, but test the *heck* out of it.  Don't rest assured that all is fine because you could connect and run a "select * from xxx" query.  Test the app thoroughly; if you are updating, test the updates, and test summarization. Repeat the tests after patching or upgrading the server or making changes to the app.

Comment: I agree with you, but i got some troubles with the newer ODBC-drivers (SQL NATIVE CLIENT 10.0). There are tables with an IDENTITY-column where the app can't insert new rows.
The old ODBC-driver works as allways.

Comment: I think it will work unless your using newer features like GPSPOINT data, etc.